# Knockout option data binding not working for the 2nd member of an object

Tags: knockout.js

Consider the HTML code for displaying a country and its population

```
<p>
    Your country:
    <select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                       optionsText: 'countryName',
                       value: selectedCountry,
                       optionsCaption: 'Select...'"></select>
</p>
<p data-bind="visible: selectedCountry">
Population for the <span data-bind= "text:selectedCountry().countryName"></span> Country is <span data-bind="text:selectedCountry().countryPopulation"></span>
</p>
```

Below is the knockout code for

```
   var Country = function(name, population) {
        this.countryName = name;
        this.countryPopulation = population;
    };

    var viewModel = {
        availableCountries : ko.observableArray([
            new Country("India", 65000000),
            new Country("UK", 320000000),
            new Country("Switzerland", 29000000)
        ]),
        selectedCountry : ko.observable() 
    };
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Only country name gets displayed not its population.

fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/raghu_jmit/1mr2dc25/

Comment: Why not write it like this `<p data-bind="visible: selectedCountry">
Population for the <span data-bind= "text: selectedCountry().countryName + ' Country is ' + selectedCountry().countryPopulation"></span>
</p>` ?, or better yet, build this string in your viewModel and then bind..

Comment: Thanks gkb, but why it doesn't work in two different spans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the console, you would have got an error - "Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return selectedCountry().countryName }"

Changing the `visible` binding to `if` should work:

```
<p data-bind="if: selectedCountry">
Population for the <span data-bind= "text:selectedCountry().countryName"></span> Country is <span data-bind="text:selectedCountry().countryPopulation"></span>
</p>
```

*Update*: Why exception thrown - As OP had optionsCaption: 'Select...' set, this value will be selected by-default and hence the selectedCountry will be empty - so selectedCountry().countryName will throw error.

Comment: can you please elaborate on why in the OP, the binding works **exclusively** for the first span after the selection is changed? I saw in the console after a value is changed, it prints `Country {countryName: "India", countryPopulation: "65000000"}`

Comment: @gkb - As OP had `optionsCaption: 'Select...'` set, this value will be selected by-default and hence the `selectedCountry` will be empty - so `selectedCountry().countryName` will throw error. And as you know in knockout, things will start screwing up from the point the template binding throws error; as far as I've seen, everything above will render properly, but the templates coming after the error part will not render properly.

Comment: so initializing the `selectedCountry` to `new Country("UK", 320000000)` to avoid the error should work?

Comment: @gkb - initializing the `selectedCountry` will again get overridden by `optionsCaption`. So I think we will end up having the same issue.

Comment: @Developer But still I didn't get the point why it works for country name which is in the first span but it doesn't for the second span - population. Both should exhibit the same behavior. What makes country name span special?

Comment: @Raghu - there is nothing special about the country name span actually. Honestly I dont have a proof here, but with my experience in knockout, this is what I _assume_ - knockout templates which appears _after_ an error will behave weird and the other templates works fine. To test what I mean, try putting the population span before the country name span - then you should be able to see the population but not the country name